# how to send and receive image through socket

Tags: android, image, sockets

I want to send an image from one android device to one or multiple android devices.
so which mechanism i should follow to send the image from one android device to another android device.
I am new to android. so if possible then give me logic(way to complete the task).
and if possible then give example of it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the WiFiDirectDemo sample in the SDK (API level 14+). It does exactly what you are looking for:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html

WiFi direct is only available for devices running ICS. However, the socket server/client code is generic and reusable over Wifi network also:

Client:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/FileTransferService.html

Server:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/DeviceDetailFragment.html
FileServerAsyncTask.

Comment: should i have to convert the image to binary array or as it is it can be send..???@Anirudh

Comment: you dont have to..just read the bytes from file's inputstream and write it over the socket's outputstream