# Need to display an image recieved through socket in android

Tags: android, image, sockets, javax.imageio, java-server

Hey I need to display an image read from socket in my android application.The android application is basically a client it receives image from a java server.The java server writes a png file using **ImageIO.write()** function.I am new to android .Can somebody please help me

Comment: Refer this answer already in stackoverflow

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939868/how-to-send-and-receive-image-through-socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the image first into byte[] array and then construct bitmap from bytes using BitmapFactory. It could look something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[imgSize];

//read all data to the buffer

BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```